# video.js ignored techorder at external servers

Tags: video.js

I have the next code

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.20.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.20.1/video.js"></script>
...
<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay width="480" height="360">
   <source src="some_rtmp_url" type="rtmp/mp4" />
   <source src="some_m3u8_url" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
</video>
...
<script>
    videojs("video", {
        techOrder : ["flash"]
    });
</script>
```

The problem is next - when i run it at local server - everything is ok, video played via flash player. But when i upload it to some external servers (dev/prod), videojs trying to open source link via html5 tech and log error:

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible
>   source was found for this media.

Any ideas why it happens? For what reason it ignore techorder?

Comment: (I'm not familiar with 'techOrder'.) But, 'flash' support is deprecated in many contexts these days, and can often get 'blocked'.  e.g. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?hl=en

Comment: Thank you Dave, for your comment. I changed "Ask first before allowing sites to run Flash." to "Allow" and it started to work. But after it i have more questions than before )

Comment: Because JWplayer (flash player) works as it should.